# How do I filter a multiindex dataframe based on columns that meet certain conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe. Columns 'partner', 'employer', and 'date' are the multiindex.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Zh6.png)

| partner | employer | date | ecom | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 10/01/21 | 1 | 0 |
| A | a | 10/02/21 | 1 | 0 |
| A | a | 10/03/21 | 0 | 1 |
| A | b | 10/01/21 | 0 | 1 |
| A | b | 10/02/21 | 1 | 0 |
| A | b | 10/03/21 | 1 | 0 |
| B | c | 10/03/21 | 1 | 0 |
| B | c | 10/04/21 | 1 | 0 |
| B | c | 10/04/21 | 0 | 1 |

I'm trying to find which unique (parter, employer) pairs have 'ecom' BEFORE 'sales'. For example, I want to have the output to be. How do I filter through each (partner, employer) pair with these conditions in python?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yCZb.png)

| partner | employer | date | ecom | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 10/01/21 | 1 | 0 |
| A | a | 10/02/21 | 1 | 0 |
| A | a | 10/03/21 | 0 | 1 |
| B | c | 10/03/21 | 1 | 0 |
| B | c | 10/04/21 | 1 | 0 |
| B | c | 10/04/21 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/463796 on how to make your question a good reproducible example, in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# Find the first date where ecom or sales is not 0
first_date = lambda col: col.first_valid_index()[-1]
tmp = df.replace(0, np.nan).sort_index().groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(
    first_ecom=('ecom', first_date),
    first_sales=('sales', first_date)
)

# The (partner, employer) pairs where ecom happens before sales
idx = tmp[tmp['first_ecom'] < tmp['first_sales']].index

# Condition to filter the original frame
cond = df.index.droplevel(-1).isin(idx)

# Result
df[cond]
```